# How can I enhance my usage of a menu layout?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How can I create a settings menu for my application that let's me show more information about the current status? With the menu layout it appears that I can only set these attributes:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/bot_engine"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings_bot_engine" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/text_to_speech"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings_text_speech" />

</menu>
```

And It displays as follows:

[image: My current layout of settings]

But I want something like this:

[image: Google Glass settings menu]

This is how Google Glass display It's settings menu.

I want the user to be able to tab over the settings to toggle them between (Active/Inactive), displaying a message:

Active (In green) or Inactive (in red).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDK menu works in the same way as the android context menu's on a phone.
It's designed for simple menus with just text and an optional icon.  If you want to do something more complex (Like the glass settings) you would need to use a CardScrollView and add your own cards to it, then you can have as much flexibility as you like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly I wanted, is a longer way but I can do it with that. Thanks!